# three.js + jquery, jquery немного сместила координаты

Tags: jquery, three.js

Имеется симуляция Солнечной системы. Сделала кнопку Earth, нажимая на которую юзер "перемещается" на Землю

```
$('#btn-earth').click(function(){
    camera.position.x = earth.position.x;
    camera.position.z = earth.position.z;
});
```

Однако, переместясь по событию, координаты слегка смещаются, примерно рядом с Землей. При этом если в анимации вот эти 2 строчки написать, все правильно, "стоишь" четко на Земле.

```
camera.position.x = earth.position.x;
camera.position.z = earth.position.z;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/oxr2maac/1/

Comment: Камера находится на орбите Земли, но почему-то неподвижно. Похоже, какой-то параметр попал в "слепую" зону события

Comment: А что делает присвоение обработчика кнопки внутри цикла анимации?

Comment: @не совсем поняла? Обработчик внутри анимации - это неверно? Готова к более грамотному коду) Но я кажется уже сама разобралась. t+=Math.PI/180*2; Должно быть до обработчика события. Теперь у меня на локалке видно движение всех планет с Земли, только пока смотрим исключительно в сторону от Солнца, будто Земля не вращается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно завести отдельную булеву переменную, значение которой будет меняться во время клика по кнопке. Если значение переменной true - следовать за Землей, если нет - оставаться на месте или перемещаться в какую-то другую статичную точку в пространстве.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;
var sun_geom, sun_mat, sun;
var earth_geom, earth_mat, earth;
var mars_geom, mars_mat, mars;
var saturn_geom, saturn_mat, saturn;
var t = 0;
var offset_y = 0;
var texture;
var r = 0.019;
var light;
var followEarth = false; // переменная для следования за Землей

init();
animate();

function init() {
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10000);
  camera.position.z = 1;
  camera.rotation.z = -Math.PI / 20;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1.4, 7000);
  light.position.set(100, 0, 0);
  light.castShadow = true;
  light.shadowMapWidth = 204;
  light.shadowMapHeight = 204;
  scene.add(light);


  sun_geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.12, 40, 40);
  texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/Map_of_the_full_sun.jpg');

  sun_mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: texture
  });
  sun = new THREE.Mesh(sun_geom, sun_mat);
  scene.add(sun);


  earth_geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(r, 10, 10);
  texture2 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8f/Whole_world_-_land_and_oceans_12000.jpg/500px-Whole_world_-_land_and_oceans_12000.jpg');
  earth_mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: texture2
  });
  earth = new THREE.Mesh(earth_geom, earth_mat);
  scene.add(earth);


  saturn_geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(2 * r, 30, 30);
  texture7 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/space-engine/images/a/a8/Jupiter_Oberfl%C3%A4che.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/640?cb=20151220023337&path-prefix=de')
  saturn_mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: texture7
  });
  saturn = new THREE.Mesh(saturn_geom, saturn_mat);
  scene.add(saturn);


  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

$('#btn-earth').click(function() {
  followEarth = !followEarth; // смена состояния следования
});

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  sun.rotation.y += 0.01;

  earth.rotation.y += 0.01;

  saturn.rotation.y += 0.01;

  earth.position.x = Math.sin(t * 0.25) * 0.25;
  earth.position.z = Math.cos(t * 0.25) * 0.25;

  saturn.position.x = Math.sin(t * 0.05) * 0.45;
  saturn.position.z = Math.cos(t * 0.05) * 0.45;

  if (followEarth) { // следуем, если значение true
    camera.position.x = earth.position.x;
    camera.position.z = earth.position.z;
  }

  t += Math.PI / 180 * 2;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/91/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn-earth" style="position: absolute;">Earth</button>
```

Comment: огромное Вам спасибо, постоянно выхожу из зоны своего комфорта, учась у Вас, голосовать не забываю))

Comment: @Наташа Благодарю за добрые слова. Голосовать - это хорошо. )) Просто ответы, отмеченные галочкой как "принятые" - лучше ищутся поисковиками и получаются более полезными для других пользователей. "Галка" находится под счетчиком плюсов-минусов у ответа.